Python Bot Fails to Select Google Ads and Window Closes Automatically
I'm working on a Python bot that needs to interact with Google Ads, but I'm encountering a couple of issues:
The bot fails to select elements related to Google Ads.
The browser window closes automatically after a short period, which is not intended.
Here's what I've tried so far:
I've used various methods from Selenium to locate and interact with elements.
I've checked for updates on all relevant libraries and ensured that my browser driver is up to date.
I've implemented exception handling to catch any errors that might indicate what's going wrong.
Despite these efforts, the issues persist. The bot is supposed to run a longer session, and interact with Google Ads without manual intervention. Here is a simplified version of my code:
import time
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from urllib.parse import urlparse

def is_allowed_domain(url, allowed_domains):
    domain = urlparse(url).netloc
    return any(domain.endswith(allowed_domain) for allowed_domain in allowed_domains)

def search_and_save_ads_to_excel(search_keyword, chromedriver_path, allowed_domains, output_excel_path):
    # Set Chrome options to open in guest profile
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--guest")

    # Set the path to the ChromeDriver executable
    service = Service(chromedriver_path)

    # Open Chrome browser with the specified options
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)

    try:
        # Maximize the browser window
        driver.maximize_window()
      
        # Navigate to Google
        driver.get("https://www.google.com")
      
        # Find the search box and enter the search keyword
        search_box = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "q")))
        search_box.send_keys(search_keyword)
        search_box.submit()
      
        # Wait for search results to load
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_any_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".g")))  

        # Find all search results
        search_results = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".g")
        
        ad_data = []
        
        for result in search_results:
            try:
                # Look for elements with specific ad attributes (e.g., data-text-ad)
                ad_elements = result.find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//div[@data-text-ad='1']")
                if ad_elements:
                    ad_url = result.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a").get_attribute("href")
                    if is_allowed_domain(ad_url, allowed_domains):
                        ad_title = result.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h3").text
                        ad_data.append({"Title": ad_title, "URL": ad_url})
                        print(f"Found Ad Title: {ad_title}")
                        print(f"Found Ad URL: {ad_url}")
                        # Click on the ad
                        result.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a").click()
                        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))  # Wait for ad page to open
                        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])  # Switch to the new window/tab
                        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "body")))  # Ensure ad page has loaded
                        time.sleep(10)  # Additional wait for ad page to load
                        driver.close()  # Close the ad page
                        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])  # Switch back to the main search results window
            except (NoSuchElementException, Exception) as e:
                print(f"Error processing result: {e}")

        # Save ad data to Excel
        df = pd.DataFrame(ad_data)
        df.to_excel(output_excel_path, index=False)
        print(f"Ad data saved to {output_excel_path}")

    finally:
        driver.quit()

# Example usage (for educational purposes only)
search_keyword = "Sikka Kaamya Greens"
chromedriver_path = r"C:/Users/J.A.S/Desktop/New folder/chromedriver.exe"  # Your ChromeDriver path (use raw string literal)
allowed_domains = ["sikka.ixapl.com", "99acres.com"]  # List of allowed domains
output_excel_path = "ad_data.xlsx"  # Output Excel file path
search_and_save_ads_to_excel(search_keyword, chromedriver_path, allowed_domains, output_excel_path)


Can anyone provide guidance on how to resolve this issue? I have been diligently working on it both day and night without success. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

welcome to StackOverflow! If you aren't getting an exception and don't know how to troubleshoot, try line-by-line debugging. It is easy to use pdb to step through your code, or learn to use your IDE's debugging tools. You can even simply open a Python REPL and paste in your commands one by one. Learning to step through your code will benefit you greatly.

In this case it's pretty simple--since your program isn't printing anything, there are only three possibilities: is_allowed_domain() is never returning True, ad_elements are not being found, or search_results are not being found. The issue is the line ad_elements = result.find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//div[@data-text-ad='1']") -- the search returns nothing and so ad_elements is an empty list. This is because you are searching from a result element but ads are not children of search result elements, they are search results. (Assuming we are talking about the same thing--I am defining an "ad" as a Google result marked with "Sponsored").
To correct this, search for ads then iterate through them:
search_box.send_keys(search_keyword)
search_box.submit()

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_any_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".g")))

ad_elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//div[@data-text-ad='1']")
for ad_element in ad_elements:
    # note: there may be multiple links in the same ad element
    ad_links = ad_element.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a") 
    ad_link = ad_links[0]
    ad_url = ad_link.get_attribute("href")
    if is_allowed_domain(ad_url, allowed_domains):
        # finding the title is not as simple as locating h3 children
        ad_title = ad_element.find_elements(...)
        ...

BTW, I get an ElementClickInterceptedException when trying to directly click() an <a> element on the search results page--I would recommend using driver.switch_to.new_window(), driver.get(ad_url) instead.

As a side note, the line except (NoSuchElementException, Exception) as e: makes no sense, because NoSuchElementException is a subclass of Exception and would be caught by using Exception alone. If you want to have different behavior for NoSuchElementException and other Exception types (which would be a good idea), use separate excepts:
except NoSuchElementException as e:
    # do something
except Exception as e:
    # do something else


Thank you So much it helps alot . I completed my bot
